# Edit an alpha variable Cobol '12.3' to '12,30 '

Tags: cobol

How does Cobol to transform a variable of this format `1234,5` to `0000000001234,50`.

```
01 VAR1  X(16) '1234,5'

01 VAR2  X(16)
01 VAROUT REDEFINES VAR2
   03 VAROUT-INT X(13)
   03 VAROUT-PNT X(01)
   03 VAROUT-DEC X(02)
STRING VAR1  DELIMITED BY ',' INTO VAR-INT
```

Comment: @MikaS close enough

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way I know.

```
   identification division.
   program-id. dpic.
   environment division.
   configuration section.
   special-names.
       decimal-point is comma.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 var1 pic x(16) value "1234,5".
   1 var2.
    2 var2-num pic 9(13),99.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       display var1
       move function numval (var1) to var2-num
       display var2
       stop run
       .
```

The result is:

```
1234,5
0000000001234,50
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used one of the general methods of editing a PICTURE clause - **Simple Insertion editing** - to achieve the expected result.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
01 WS-A   PIC X(16) VALUE '1234,5'.
01 WS-B   PIC 9999999999999,90.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MOVE WS-A TO WS-B.
DISPLAY WS-B.
STOP RUN.
```

Result: 
    `0000000001234,50`